# Relaunch Fargate Task Before Stop the World Garbage Collection

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, garbage-collection, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-fargate

I have an ECS service with multiple tasks running a Java web application.  We have a memory leak which causes the memory on each task to increase over time. When the memory usage gets to about 90%, Java runs a full / stop the world garbage collection that can pause the task for upwards of 10 seconds. Our long term solution is to fix the leak.  In the meantime, I'd like to relaunch the task when it's memory usage surpasses 75%. How can I trigger a healthy Fargate TASK to relaunch when the task's memory exceeds 75%?

Comment: What metric exactly are you referring to when talking about "memory increase"? VMZ? RSS? Some kind of internal Java metric?

Comment: in our task definition, we simply set the 'memory' property (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html). Also in the task definition, we set the Java jvm parameter -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0 which sets the maximum Java heap size to be equal to 75% of the available memory.  The task runs a Linux container but we're not specifying anything about RSS or VSZ.

Comment: "When the memory usage gets to about 90%": how do you know it happens? where exactly are you looking?

Answer (score 0):

If you send an HTTP request to `${ECS_CONTAINER_METADATA_URI_V4}/task/stats` it will give you the current live stats for your containers. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4-fargate.html

Run a tiny sidecar container in your task that is marked as `essential: true` so that if it stops then the task is stopped and replaced. Inside of that sidecar run a little bash script that runs forever and checks the task stats to see if memory utilization has exceeded your threshold. If it has then the script exits. When the script exits the sidecar container will exit and the task will be marked as unhealthy in ECS and replaced.